# Hiding putty terminal while running in Batch script

Tags: batch-file, putty

I am running my shell script connecting to remote server through putty, in a batch script as:

```
putty.exe -ssh -2 user@sever.com -pw password -m command.cmd
```

where, command.cmd contains

```
cd /path/to/the/script
./name.ksh
```

It is running 100% correct, as I needed.But here, the putty terminal is appearing while the batch script is running, which I donot want.

Is there any way to hide the putty terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible using batch, use vbscript:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "putty.exe -ssh -2 user@sever.com -pw password -m command.cmd", 0
' 0 => hide
```

Comment: I am using it to open gnome terminal using xming. So that I get a better terminal, than the default one for putty.

Comment: Thanks anishsane, I got the required result.Is it possible to show a MsgBox("Completed successfully."), when the processing of putty.exe is done.As I tried, it is prompting after immidiate execution of WshShell.run command.Prompt should be after the successful execution of putty.exe.Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have a look at [this link](http://ss64.com/vb/run.html) . Set `bWaitOnReturn` = true. & After the run statement, put your msgbox statement normally.